# Optimization triangular prism

Tags: optimization

I am working on a math project on optimisation and have a triangular prism (tent) with a given volume of 2.8 cubic meters. The "top" of the tent is out of a water-resistant material for 2.25 dollars per square meter, and the floor material costs 1.75 dollars per square meter. I am supposed to find the dimensions of the tent while minimizing the costs. I just spent these past two hours trying to figure it out without much outcome. I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean triangular pyramid? A triangular prism has a triangle for a top and a bottom, which does not look like a tent.

Comment: @kccu Turn the prism on it’s side, like a pup tent with a floor.

Comment: I see, I was picturing a tent with one point at the top.

Comment: So, is the tent a *prism*, as you’ve written, or a *tetrahedron* (pyramid)? The answer you accepted solves the problem for the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b,c$ are the sides of base and $h$ is the height of prizm.
Then the area of base is
$$S_b = {1\over4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)},$$
the volume is
$$V = S_bh$$
and required quantity of material is
$$S = S_b + (a+b+c)h.$$
Using the condition $V=2.8,$ we have $h={2.8\over S_b},$ so we have to minimize
$$S = S_b + 2.8\,{a+b+c\over S_b},$$
$$S={1\over4}\sqrt{a+b+c}\sqrt{(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}$$
$$+{11.2\,\sqrt{a+b+c}\over\sqrt{(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}}.$$
for $a, b, c >0.$

Using [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min%201%2F4*%5Csqrt%7Ba%2Bb%2Bc%7D%5Csqrt%7B(-a%2Bb%2Bc)(a-b%2Bc)(a%2Bb-c)%7D%2B%7B11.2%5Csqrt%7Ba%2Bb%2Bc%7D%5Cover%5Csqrt%7B(-a%2Bb%2Bc)(a-b%2Bc)(a%2Bb-c)%7D%7D), one can get
$$S=10.3226\text{ at }(a, b, c)\approx(2.81892, 2.81892, 2.81892),\ h\approx 0,27125$$
with the price
$$10.3226\cdot1.75 = 18,06455.$$

Comment: Your are welcome!

Comment: The “tent” that you’ve posited here is a tetrahedron, not a prism as stated in the OP.

Comment: And what does the author of the question say? As I understand, the prizm requires less material per the volume. =)

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to an optimization problem of a function of 3 variables subject to a constraint:

You can vary 3 parameters (height, base width, base length), for which you have a "Price Function" which is the sum of all the material times its respective cost (this is a trivial problem in geometry). Thus you wish to minimize the "price function" c(h,w,l)

You are constrained by the fact that the volume (also a function of h,l,w) is constrained.

This is the textbook application of Lagrange Multipliers. If you are unfamiliar with them, I would check out Paul's Online or Khan Academy, as they both provide great explanations. I hope this helps!